# TWILIO REST API Helper Library - Issue with NewtonSoft.Json Version

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

We have installed the latest Twilio version(5.69.0) in our .NET project (.NETFramework Version is 4.6.2)and updated the following.

```
Microsoft.Identitymodel.Token (Version:6.15.0)
System.Identity.Model.Token.jwt (Version:6.15.0)
Newtonsoft.Json- (Version:12.0.2)
In the description it is said that we can use Newtonsoft.Json version >=10.0.1(Please see the screenshot)
```

But we are getting the following error.

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'
   at Twilio.Clients.TwilioRestClient.ProcessResponse(Response response)
   at Twilio.Clients.TwilioRestClient.Request(Request request)
   at Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.RecordingResource.Read(ReadRecordingOptions options, ITwilioRestClient client)
   at Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account.RecordingResource.Read
```

[image: Nuget Description]

Please advise.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please note: We can't use NewtonSoft.Json version 10.0.1 and can only use version > 12.0 since we are using push notification feature in our application.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you need to contact the Vendor

Answer (score 1):

Hi Twilio Evangelist here,

Sorry that you're having this issue. This unfortunately is one that comes up from time to time. I'm not entirely sure that this is caused by Twilio and unfortunately, we've not been able to reproduce it.

However here are some options that may help you get going here.

1. You can use the `bindingRedirect` feature to force .NET to use a specific version of Newtonsoft.JSON in your project. If you have an app.config (or a web.config) file, you can include this in the runtime element of your config file. Below is an example

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0-12.0.2" newVersion="12.0.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

2. You can reach out to me at corey[at]twilio.com via email if you need additional support.

Comment: This code snippet isn't even valid XML. Where's the opening tag for `dependentAssembly`?

Comment: @JacobStamm thanks for calling that out. I've updated it to both fix that issue & add the detailed assemblyBinding namespace. This has just been verified